# Only get row with particular ID and timestamp if other row with same ID and timestamp does not exist

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I use T-SQL to import and transform data from an Azure database which is used to create visualizations for our customers in Power BI.

What I've got:

A table with measurement data. Each data value is associated with a particular timestamp, unitid, and datatype.

[image]

What I'd like to have is a table containing:

1. rows with only datatype apparent-power *if both* uncalibrated-current *and* apparent-power exists for a given Unitid and timestamp.
2. rows with datatype uncalibrated-current *if only* uncalibrated-current *and not* apparent-power exists for a given unitid and timestamp.

If apparent-power exists for a given timestamp and unitid, then uncalibrated-current always exists too. There are other datatypes in the data set than the two mentioned.

To visualize, I would like a table that only contains the rows marked in green in the below images:

[image]
[image]

I have searched the problem intensively, but I must admit my SQL skills are still too limited to find or create a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when datatype = 'apparent-power' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by unitid, timestamp) as cnt_ap,
             sum(case when datatype = 'uncalibrated-current' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by unitid, timestamp) as cnt_uc
      from t
     ) t
where datatype = 'apparent-power' and cnt_uc > 0 or
      datatype = 'uncalibrated-current' and cnt_ap = 0;
```

If I understand correctly, you can also use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datatype = 'apparent_power' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.unitid = t.unitid and
                        t2.timestamp = t.timestamp and
                        t2.datatype = 'apparent_power'
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. The window functions example works fine, and it doesn't seem to slow down thew query noticeably. I ended up using the equivalent to this in my query, as it doesn't essentially matter if uncalibrated-current exists or not:

select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when datatype = 'apparent-power' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by unitid, timestamp) as cnt_ap,
      from t
     ) t
where datatype = 'apparent-power' or
      datatype = 'uncalibrated-current' and cnt_ap = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's best to split the problem in 2 parts using UNION ALL will append 2 tables so you can focus only on getting all apparent-power, and then only on uncalibrated-current

then it's just a task of filtering:

```
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.* 
    FROM T AS T1
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM T WHERE DataType = 'uncalibrated-current') AS T2 
        ON T1.UnitID = T2.UnitID AND T1.TimeStamp = T2.TimeStamp
    WHERE T1.DataType = 'apparent-power'
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
    FROM T AS T1
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM T WHERE DataType = 'apparent-power') AS T2 
        ON T1.UnitID = T2.UnitID AND T1.TimeStamp = T2.TimeStamp
    WHERE T1.DataType = 'uncalibrated-current'
        AND T2.DataType IS NULL
)
```

First query has a `INNER JOIN`, effectively filtering out anything that doesn't match.
Second query is known as an ANTI JOIN filtering out everything that does match (`T2.DataType IS NULL`)

Finally, the `DISTINCT` on both tables is to account for the fact that those joins will duplicate rows if you have more then those 2 DataType's

Comment: Thank you, I wil be looking further into this in the coming week.